# What's line-height (and element height) if font-size is set to 1rem?

Tags: css, font-size

font set to 1rem, but the line-height as well as element height are more than that

```css
.box {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>FRONT</div>
</div>
```

I managed to work out that box height is 1.167rem Is that exactly the height of element containing text sized 1rem? I'm not sure. What is that 0.167rem?

Why is it this much? What's called this 'gap' above and below the element/text?

Comment: 1rem is equal html font-size

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the default line-height (which is slightly higher than the font size) set by browsers to make text readable. You can explicitly set some `line-height` here, for e.g. `line-height: 1` to make the element's height the same as the text font size. The value of `line-height` will work in multiples, like `line-height: 1.2` will be `font-size * 1.2`.